# Setting end session endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

With a Spring Boot client configured in the DMZ and Spring Security OAuth configured using:

```
issuer-uri: https://authentication_server/auth/realms/my-realm
```

I get this error from Spring Security:

```
The Issuer "https://external_url/auth/realms/my-realm" provided in the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer "https://authentication_server/auth/realms/my-realm
```

From [this post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9019) I have learned that I need to specify `authorization-uri`, `token-uri` and `jwk-set-uri` instead of `issuer-uri`, and then it also works.

```
authorization-uri: https://external_url/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token-uri: https://authentication_server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
jwk-set-uri: https://authentication_server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

(I do not get why Spring Security cannot auto-configure with the same values from the `issuer-uri` when it works setting the values individually)

Now the problem is that logout stops working. When using `issuer-uri` the OAuth is auto-configured and `end_session_endpoint` is fetched from the answer, but when specifying each setting there is no way to specify the `end_session_endpoint`.

Is this an outstanding issue in Spring Security OAuth, or do I need to configure it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to make a work around for this. With little time I started by copying the existing [OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/web/logout/OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler.java) which I already were using in configuring LogoutRedirectUri.

I simply copied the class and changed the implementation of the method `endSessionEndpoint()` to return the URI which is returned by our OAuth server as `end_session_endpoint`.

This issue is [tracked in spring-security GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10059).
Probable fix will be [allowing to add "Additional attributes for ClientRegistration and ProviderDetails"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9669).